# how to connect to main db use django pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, pytest

I am using Django and pytest in my project.
I need to write tests based on data in the main database. But pytest cleans up and creates a clean database every test run session. I need to use the main DB, which is specified in `settings.py`. I need a way without copying all the data of the main database to the test one!

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_my_user():
    me = User.objects.get(username='me')
    assert me.is_superuser
```

I want the information to be taken from the main database in this case.

Comment: I am not sure this is the right approach to generate a test. If you want to create a test you want it to be independent of other parts. So it might be better to generate some possible returns from the Database (different `User` objects) and test if your function is returning the correct reply on those inputs.

Comment: do you know a way to do it?

Comment: Without knowing anything of your structure or what you want to test, I can only guess. But I see a User model, for which we can generate a fake user something like: `User(id=5, is_superuser=False)`, and then apply your function that you want to test.